# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused en despliegue Laravel 9.0

Tags: mysql, laravel-9

Buenos días compañeros.

Recientemente he desplegado en mi hosting un nuevo proyecto de laravel que he actualizado de la versión 8.x a la 9.x. El proyecto funciona con total normalidad en local pero al subirlo al hosting me lanza un error de conexión con la base de datos. He revisado la configuración de la base de datos en el archivo .ENV y es correcta y semejante a otros proyectos que ya tengo desplegados y funcionando. Os adjunto captura de pantalla del error:

[image: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema o le ha ocurrido?

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Pues revisa a qué base de datos y con qué usuario / contraseña está conectado tu aplicación y comprueba que dicha BD exista en el entorno remoto, que las credenciales sean las correctas y que ese usuario tiene los permisos adecuados en dicha base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se generaba al no compilar correctamente la aplicación por la versión de node con npm run dev.

Un saludo.